# admin-ajax Firing Error 400 When Logged In

Tags: php, ajax, javascript

Ah *yes*, the ol' admin-ajax error 400 issue. I have looked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/400-bad-request-on-admin-ajax-php-only-using-wp-enqueue-scripts-action-hook) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/336906/error-400-bad-request-using-admin-ajax-php) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341599/ajax-call-doesnt-work-in-frontend-but-its-working-in-backend-when-im-logged) for a solution and none of those fixed my problem. So before this is marked as a duplicate, please just hear me out.

My admin-ajax link looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var ajaxurl = "https://full-url.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
</script>
```

My AJAX call looks like this:

```
var data = {
    action: 'get_events'
};

jQuery.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  data: data,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){ 
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(thrownError);
  }
});
```

And inside my functions.php, I have the following:

```
add_action('get_events', 'get_events_func');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_events', 'get_events_func');

function get_events_func() {

    echo 'please work';
    exit(); 
    
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I am logged out of the website, but once I am logged in, it throws an error 400. Did I set up that `wp_ajax_nopriv_` hook wrong? That's the only thing I can think of.

The error response I am getting is simply:

```
XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, abort: ƒ, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ ()
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: ƒ ()
ontimeout: null
readyState: 4
response: "0"
responseText: "0"
responseType: ""
responseURL: "https://full-url.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
responseXML: null
status: 400
statusText: ""
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequest

400

undefined
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you've carefully reviewed those linked answers? Because that `add_action('get_events',` should be `add_action('wp_ajax_get_events',` ..

Comment: @SallyCJ o. m. g. 
If you put this as answer, I'll mark it as the solution. I've never felt so dumb. Thank you.

Comment: It's alright, everyone makes mistakes.. =) And I've posted an answer, but you should, specially if you're just starting out with `admin-ajax.php`, consider using the REST API instead. It's well-documented and you can do things like retrieving [Posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/), Pages, CPT posts, custom taxonomy terms, etc. What's more, you'd get a better response body/text (well, at least it's not simply a `0`..) when an error is encountered during an API request, so debugging would become easier than with the ol' `admin-ajax.php`.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I set up that `wp_ajax_nopriv_` hook wrong?

No, you did not. But that hook is for logged-out or unregistered users only.

For logged-in users, the hook is `wp_ajax_<action>`.

So you just need to change the `add_action('get_events'` in your code to `add_action('wp_ajax_get_events'`, and the error 400 would be gone:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_get_events', 'get_events_func');        // for logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_events', 'get_events_func'); // for logged-out users
```